# Not adding element by element to JList until for loop ends

Tags: java, timer, jlist

I'm making a Algorithm simulator for an assignment, I need to show line by line in the algorithm.

This is my insertion sort algo code:

```
private void insertionSort(int array[]) {
    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    algoShowingList.setModel(dlm);

    MyTimerTask mt = new MyTimerTask();

    int key, i = 0;

    for (int j = 1; j <= array.length - 1; j++) {
        dlm.removeAllElements();
        dlm.addElement("1. for j = " + (j + 1) + " to " + array.length);
        System.out.println("1. for j = " + (j + 1) + " to " + array.length);
        mt.delayRunning();

        dlm.addElement("2.     key = " + array[j]);
        System.out.println("2.     key = " + array[j]);
        key = array[j];
        mt.delayRunning();


        dlm.addElement("3.     i = " + i);
        System.out.println("3.     i = " + i);
        i = j - 1;
        mt.delayRunning();

        dlm.addElement("4.     while " + i + ">0 and " + array[i] + ">" + key);
        while (i > 0 && array[i] > key) {
            dlm.removeElementAt(3);
            dlm.addElement("4.     while " + i + ">0 and " + array[i] + ">" + key);


            if (algoShowingList.getLastVisibleIndex() == 4) {
                dlm.removeElementAt(4);
            }
            dlm.addElement("5.         array[" + (i + 1) + "] = " + array[i]);
            //changing txtfield colors
            changeColorToRed(findTextField(array[i + 1]));
            changeColorToGreen(findTextField(array[i]));

            array[i + 1] = array[i];
            printInitialArray(array);
            changeColorToGreen(findTextField(array[i + 1]));

            if (algoShowingList.getLastVisibleIndex() == 5) {
                dlm.removeElementAt(5);
            }
            dlm.addElement("6.         i = " + i);
            i = i - 1;
        }

        dlm.addElement("7. Array[" + (i + 1) + "] = " + key);
        array[i + 1] = key;
        printInitialArray(array);
        changeColorToRed(findTextField(key));

        resetTextFieldColorToDefault();
        printOneLoopInsertionSort(array, j);
    }

}
```

by calling  mt.delayRunning(); i can delay executing next line for 3 secs, my problem is i want to add element by element to JList when code is running.

```
        dlm.addElement("1. for j = " + (j + 1) + " to " + array.length);
        System.out.println("1. for j = " + (j + 1) + " to " + array.length);
        mt.delayRunning();

        dlm.addElement("2.     key = " + array[j]);
        System.out.println("2.     key = " + array[j]);
        key = array[j];
        mt.delayRunning();
```

Like this System.out.println() is printing line by line i want to add element to JList, but it adds only when for loop ended and all lines added at once for the last loop.

output in console----------

1. for j = 2 to 10          -sout  prints but not adding to JList

TimerTask started

Timer task started at:Thu Sep 11 10:35:13 IST 2014

TimerTask cancelled

Timer task finished at:Thu Sep 11 10:35:16 IST 2014

2. key = 9             -sout  prints but not adding to JList

TimerTask started

Timer task started at:Thu Sep 11 10:35:19 IST 2014

TimerTask cancelled

Timer task finished at:Thu Sep 11 10:35:22 IST 2014

3. i = 0              -sout  prints but not adding to JList

TimerTask started

Timer task started at:Thu Sep 11 10:35:25 IST 2014

TimerTask cancelled

Timer task finished at:Thu Sep 11 10:35:28 IST 2014

All elements added to JList when loop ends, i need to show one by one, can someone please help me!
i can't find why this is happening!

Answer (score 0):

Swing is a single threaded environment, this means two (basic) things, first, you should never block the Event Dispatching Thread in anyway (include `Thread.sleep`), as this will prevent the UI from been updated.  Second, you should never update or modify the UI in anyway other then from within the context of the EDT.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Now, there are probably any number of ways you might achieve this, but the simplest might be to use a `SwingWorker`, do the sort (and pause) within the context of the `doInBackground` method and use `publish`/`process` to update the UI, that way you won't be blocking the Event Dispatching Thread

See [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. can you please give me an example? Like how to modify my code?

Comment: dlm.addElement("1. for j = " + (j + 1) + " to " + array.length);
                System.out.println("1. for j = " + (j + 1) + " to " + array.length);

                //
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(3000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                });

Comment: from this i can add one element as i wanted, but it gives me a "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread"   can you please help me with this?

Comment: I'm not ignoring you, not in front of PC

Comment: it's ok, when you get back can you please answer, still i'm stuck with this!